# Good API for mindflow type application

Tags: java, api, user-interface, mindmap

I'm going to be programming a mind node type of application, namely one that allows text editing within text bubbles, free form movement of the bubbles, small bits of animation, but all the standard properties of a windowed application.

I've only done game programming before, where all elements have to be adjusted and programmed, including the GUI etc. Now that I've decided to try my hand at a more "standard" utility program, I'm at a loss of what kinds of API's I should be looking for.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) for that, putting two [collapsible tree layouts](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html) side by side. That's what we did for our own [mindmapping tool](http://sutoiku.com/post/41279461033/mindmap-perspective), and it took about a day to get the layout right. It's in JavaScript though, not Java, but I'm sure you could integrate it with you Java back-end fairly easily. If you're using a Java applet, it won't be of much help though, but I really hope you don't, for they're a dying breed...